# Word Categories

Tags: word, pattern, wordplay, rhyme

Below are three groups of clues. Within each group, the answers share a common characteristic. The groups also share a common characteristic. Solving any one group should make it much easier to solve the others.

**Group A**

> 1. Trend toward fervor
> 2. Packing a teddy bear for your first sleepover
> 3. Aborigine traditional dress
> 4. Tongue-twister
> 5. Predilection toward deities
> 6. One who hugs programmers
> 7. Forgiveness for killing someone
> 8. Uncertainty about rainforests
> 9. A lie about involvement in a crime
> 10. Predisposition toward rage

**Group B**

> 1. Tantrum play-by-play
> 2. Advocation for cremation
> 3. Flawed point of view
> 4. Declaration of independence
> 5. Plan for improved air quality
> 6. Investigator-in-training
> 7. Plan for a new waste-treatment facility
> 8. Gemstone perplexity
> 9. Careful look into the sudden change in leadership
> 10. Act of getting covered for eventualities

**Group C**

> 1. Limitation put on a photograph
> 2. Discouraged group of firefighters
> 3. Document exempting human traffickers
> 4. Less-than-brilliant hue
> 5. Religious ceremonies of young ladies
> 6. Very accurate gadget
> 7. Expressing a poem non-vocally
> 8. Well-ploughed section of a field
> 9. Intelligent choice for private air travel
> 10. Item in the Munitions Hall of Fame

Comment: Here are a few: c1='picture stricture', c4='duller color', c6='precise device'; a few more questionable ones: c3=? 'papers slavers', c5=? 'rites sprites', c8=? 'bright flight'

Comment: C7: Terse verse? C9: Smarter charter.

Comment: 2 blue crew; 3 slaver waiver; 5 festal vestals; 7 mime a rhyme

Comment: At first I thought B was much the same as **C** and saw **8** youth sleuth. But **B2** fire sale; **3** false perspective; **5** breath control; and **B8** Ruby cube seem more promising.

Comment: i think C5 = masses of lassess

Comment: Some of the above are correct. Many are not.

Comment: I think B1 = drama...?

Comment: I really wish the comments weren't full of spoilers.

Comment: Seriously, why are people answering in the comments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I've done and gathered from the comments (wiki)

```
Group A
1. Trend toward fervor                                | ✓ intensity propensity
2. Packing a teddy for your first sleepover           | ✓ separation preparation  
3. Aborigine traditional dress                        | ✓ Australia Regalia
4. Tongue-twister                                     | ✓ elocution convolution
5. Predilection toward deities                        | ✓ divinity affinity
6. One who hugs programmers                           | ✓ developer enveloper
7. Forgiveness for killing someone                    | ✓ execution absolution
8. Uncertainty about rainforests                      | ✓ humidity timidity
9. A lie about involvement in a crime                 | ✓ complicity duplicity -or- perpetration fabrication
10. Predisposition toward rage                        | ✓ lividity proclivity
```

-

```
Group B 
1. Tantrum play-by-play                               | ✓ conniption description
2. Advocation for cremation                           | ✓ interment determent
3. Flawed point of view                               | ✓ defective perspective
4. Declaration of independence                        | ✓ secession expression
5. Plan for improved air quality                      | ✓ pollution solution
6. Investigator-in-training                           | ✓ prospective detective
7. Plan for a new waste-treatment facility            | ✓ disposal proposal
8. Gemstone perplexity                                | ✓ corundum conundrum -or- jewelry foolery
9. Careful look into the sudden change in leadership  | ✓ mutiny scrutiny
10. Act of getting covered for eventualities          | ✓ insurance procurance
```

-

```
Group C     
1. Limitation put on a photograph                     | ✓ picture stricture
2. Discouraged group of firefighters                  | ✓ dismayed brigade
3. Document exempting human traffickers               | ✓ slaver waiver 
4. Less-than-brilliant hue                            | ✓ duller colour 
5. Religious ceremonies of young ladies               | ✓ lasses' masses
6. Very accurate gadget                               | ✓ precise device    
7. Expressing a poem non-vocally                      | ✓ miming rhyming
8. Well-ploughed section of a field                   | ✓ thorough furrow   
9. Intelligent choice for private air travel          | ✓ smarter charter   
10. Item in the Munitions Hall of Fame                | ✓ displayed grenade
```

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the number of rhyming syllables or just syllables..

Comment: c5: lasses' masses?

Comment: It's a wiki, please feel free to jump in and add things as you see fit!

Comment: Looks like in group A, the words have 4 syllables each, in B 3 syllables, and in C 2 syllables

Comment: How is proclivity something that happens after death (as per the hint)? I can't seem to find any definition on that. I didn't put lividity proclivity because it didn't match the hint...

Comment: @orp 'lividity' is the part that happens after death (and is semi-synonymous with 'rage', as the hint mentions). The only reason I'm not crazy about it as an answer is that it doesn't really rhyme.

Comment: @question_asker: I looked back at the edit history and it turns out I misread the hint. Derp.

Comment: @orp yeah I re-read the hint just to make sure and I can definitely see where the confusion came from